# Flutter fails on `flutter` command

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm following the [Getting Started with Flutter](http://flutter.io/getting-started/) guide and getting stuck when running the actual `flutter` command:

```
flutter init -o my_app
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 17, column 16 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "^1.4.0". Unknown text at "^1.4.0".
  stack_trace: ^1.4.0
               ^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/Users/craig/Code/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/packages/sky_tools/executable.dart' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
Stack Trace:
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:349)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1151)
#2      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:496)
#3      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:579)
#4      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:339)
#5      _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:401)
#6      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#7      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#8      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#9      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)

#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:883)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/Users/craig/Code/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
Stack Trace:
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:349)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1151)
#2      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:496)
#3      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:579)
#4      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:339)
#5      _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:401)
#6      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#7      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#8      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#9      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)

#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:883)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:84)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:131)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like your Dart version is outdated `< 1.9.2`.
Try `dart --version` to get the version of your installed Dart SDK.
Current is `1.12.x`.

**Update 2018-03-20**

During the migration phase to Dart 2 you might want to install Dart from the `dev` channel to get a 2.0.0-alpha.x version.
The newest stable version is 1.24.x

For example

```
brew install dart --devel
```

**Update 2018-06-21**

Now also supported:

```
brew install dart@2
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I had two versions installed and the older one was taking precedence. I removed both and installed latest and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

For others who're facing a similar error, I suggest that you read the docs carefully. I didn't, hence I wasted quite some time looking out for the solution elsewhere, even though it was right in front of my eyes all the time: https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#update-your-path

I'm writing the commands down so that you can copy and paste them easily in your terminal window:

```
touch $HOME/.bash_profile
open $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Line 1 creates a text file named `.bash_profile`. Line 2 opens it.

Then the line given below has to be pasted in the text file:

```
export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Don't forget to save the file after pasting. `flutter doctor` should work with every Terminal window now.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and run this

```
export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

then run **flutter**, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you the path you set up is temporary. To add the path

```
export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY] -> Folder where you downloaded flutter or cloned from git.

Then do

```
echo $PATH
```

Watch this video to easy install 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em8igImhBKc